# Creating a BAT file for manage-bde with user input in Win7

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to create a batch file to run manager-bde in order to check Bitlocker status on PCs in our organization where it will prompt for the user to input the PC name in order to complete the command. Not sure if this is even possible. Currently I just manually edit the file each time I need to run it.

Here is what I have so far:

```
@ECHO OFF
cmd /k manage-bde -status -cn
```

I need the prompt to add the PC name after the `-cn` switch. Is this even possible?

Comment: with "PC name" - do you mean the environment variable `%computername%`? (would be fine - it's better to ask the machine instead the user)

Comment: @Stephan - Great point. I updated my answer to incorporate this tidbit in the event that is the intent of the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prompt for the machine by using the `SET /P` command.

Note that when you do this, you will want to make sure the user enters a value, otherwise the command will fail (as `%Machine%` would expand to an empty value).

Here is your code updated with the prompt and validation:

```
@ECHO OFF

:GetMachine
SET "Machine="
SET /P Machine=Enter machine name:

REM Verify input was received.
IF "%Machine%"=="" (
    ECHO Please enter a machine name.
    GOTO GetMachine
)

REM Append input to the command.
cmd /k manage-bde -status -cn %Machine%
```

---

**Edit:** As noted by a commenter above, if you only want this to look at the current machine, you can just use the system `%ComputerName%` variable (no prompt needed):

```
@ECHO OFF
cmd /k manage-bde -status -cn %ComputerName%
```

Comment: ... or just `manage-bde -status` to check the current machine.

Answer (score 0):

Use `set /p` to input anything into a batch program.

```
@echo off
REM Input the computer name here:
set /p COMP_NAME="Enter computer name:"
cmd /k manage-bde -status -cn %COMP_NAME%
pause
```